# Can digital servo motors be modified for continuous rotation?

Tags: mobile-robot, rcservo

In an autonomous mobile robot, we're planning on using digital servo motors to drive the wheels. Servo motors usually don't rotate continuously. However, they can be modified to do so based on many tutorials online which only mention modifying [analog] servo motors.

My question is, can the same method(s) or any other ones be used to modify *digital* servo motors?

Thanks

Comment: Any particular reason you're not just using a stepper motor? Or a DC motor with an encoder?

Comment: Nop. I'm researching now stepper motors. Any "pointing in the right direction" as to where to look for is appreciated.

Comment: @Mark Booth 

The other question asks about stepper motors. The answers talk about servo motors and stepper motors but not digital servo motors. Thanks

Comment: It is a duplicate not because it is asking the same question, but because the answers are the same.

Comment: Also, by the look of it when you are referring to "digital servo motors" you appear to be referring to [tag:rcservo] rather than [tag:servomotor] as your tags suggest. If you edit your question such that answers on the duplicated question are not appropriate, then this question can be re-opened. At the very least you will need to tell us which "digital servo motor" you are planning to use, since servomotors usually *can* continuously rotate if they are not constrained by the mechanical components they are connected to.

Comment: Yup, [tag:digitalservo]s are [tag:rcservo]s, so I have added a [tag synonym](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/tags/rcservo/synonyms).

Comment: I have also updated the question this is marked as a duplicate of to make it clear it is also asking about rcservo motors rather than stepper motors.

Comment: Ok fair enough.
And thanks for your efforts @MarkBooth :)